# How to install a package without marking it as manually installed?

Tags: debian, apt

How can I install a debian package but make apt consider it automatically installed? I.e. if I later run `apt-get autoremove`, this package would be uninstalled.

Answer (score 7):

The best way I've found is to run:

```
apt-get install mypackage myotherpackage
apt-mark auto mypackage myotherpackage
```

If you have aptitude installed, you can also do:

```
aptitude -o Aptitude::Delete-Unused=false install mypackage+M myotherpackage+M
```